# How to Execute Code on Unity's Main Thread After Completing a Task?

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a Unity project where I need to perform certain operations asynchronously using Tasks, and then apply the results (such as updating the UI or modifying game objects) on the main thread. While I understand that Unity's main thread is essential for such operations to avoid runtime errors, I'm encountering difficulties in ensuring that code execution returns to the main thread after completing tasks.

I've already experimented with several approaches to tackle this issue, including:

Coroutines: Attempted to start a coroutine from within the task's continuation, but it seems like the coroutine doesn't execute in the expected manner, or the transition back to the main thread isn't happening as I anticipated.

Custom Dispatcher Classes: Created classes similar to what's often referred to as UnityMainThreadDispatcher, Dispatcher, and MainThreadExecutor, which are supposed to enqueue actions to be executed on the main thread during the Update loop. However, these solutions haven't been reliable for my needs, either due to execution not happening at all or other synchronization issues.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
   // Perform some asynchronous operation
   Debug.Log("Perform some asynchronous operation");
})
.ContinueWith(t => StartCoroutine(ExecuteOnMainThread()));
private IEnumerator ExecuteOnMainThread()
{
   // Code that needs to run on the main thread, e.g., UI updates
   Debug.Log("Code that needs to run on the main thread, e.g., UI updates");
   yield return null;
}
```

If I execute this code only the "Perform some asynchronous operation" pops up, it never displays the "Code that needs to run on the main thread, e.g., UI updates".

I've seen various suggestions and code snippets online, but none have worked flawlessly in my scenario. I'm reaching out to see if anyone has successfully managed to execute code on the main thread from within a Task in Unity and would be willing to share their approach or insights.

Specifically, I'm looking for a solution that is:

Reliable across different Unity versions (I'm currently using Unity 2023.2.6f1 LTS).
Suitable for tasks that involve significant asynchronous operations, including web requests and data processing.
Capable of handling exceptions that may occur in tasks and ensuring that the main thread execution can still proceed safely.
If you've faced similar challenges and found a working solution or if you have any suggestions on improving the methods I've tried, I would greatly appreciate your advice.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @adrian-sgro for your reply, that helped my figure out how to solve my problem. I wanted to share an update on my quest to execute code on Unity's main thread from within a Task. After trying various methods, including custom dispatcher classes like UnityMainThreadDispatcher, I've found a solution that works for my specific case.

Initially, my attempts involved creating a separate class to manage a queue of actions (Action) that needed to be executed on the main thread. Despite ensuring this class was attached to an active GameObject and the script was enabled, the Update method in this dispatcher class was not being called by Unity as expected.

Here's how I resolved the issue:

I moved the action queue directly into my main class, where I already had other Unity-specific logic (like handling user inputs or updating the game state). Here's the simplified structure of what I did:

Declare the Action Queue:
Inside my main MonoBehaviour class, I declared a private static action queue.

```
private static Queue<Action> actions = new Queue<Action>();
```

Enqueue Actions from a Task:
Whenever I needed to execute something on the main thread as a result of a task completion, I enqueued the action like this:

```
actions.Enqueue(() =>
{
    Debug.Log("Test Enqueue from Task");
});
```

Process the Queue in Update:
I added a loop inside the Update method of the same MonoBehaviour class to process and execute the actions.

```
while (actions.Count > 0)
{
    Debug.Log("Update called with " + actions.Count + " actions in queue");
    Action action = null;
    lock (actions)
    {
        if (actions.Count > 0)
        {
            action = actions.Dequeue();
        }
    }
    action?.Invoke();
}
```

Conclusion:

It seems that, for some reason, the separate class was initialized correctly, but Unity was not calling its Update method. By integrating the action queue directly into my main MonoBehaviour class, I ensured that actions enqueued from tasks were executed on the main thread as intended.

This approach may not be ideal for every scenario, but it resolved my specific issue with executing code on the main thread following asynchronous operations.

I hope this solution might help others facing similar challenges. If anyone has insights into why the Update method might not have been called in the separate class scenario, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that can be solved several ways but i will share my favourite that is extensively used in Network libraries.
Make a Queue of actions (You can make a queue of objects that call those actions if you want to make it more clean), add an action when you need to update you UI and check for new actions in Unity update/late update. When you find any element in your queue, execute them and remove them from the queue.
This ensures that all execution calls are always on the Unity thread so you can modify Unity components as UI elements while retaining the ability to modify the queue outside the Unity thread.